# The cipher puzzle

Tags: cipher

One day, I found this crumpled up note. It said:

```
The M3, beta 3 ring 3,1 position 3 ring 3,1 position 3 ring 3, 1 position 3 ring 3, UKW c thin, gpayi isnjx xkxxs bjuqb xfjhp tfmit ouuf
```

So, what is the youtube video?

Comment: If your video is about lobster: What about editing the note in your question like "The M4, beta 3 ring 3,1 position 3 ring 3,1 position 3 ring 3, 1 position 3 ring 3, UKW b thin, GPAYI ISNJX XKXXS BJUQB XFJHP *2* TFMIt OUUF"? Fixed Enigma settings and added clue for missing number and casing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The note must have been very crumpled indeed.

This is an

> Enigma cipher

but it doesn't really work at all:

- The M3 doesn't use the beta ring, nor can it use thin UKWs. The M4 does.
- The complete set only has one of each ring, you cannot put the same ring into multiple slots at the same time.
- Youtube URLs are case sensitive, this cipher is not.
- Youtube URLs can contain numbers, this cipher can not represent them.

So I'm really not going to bother with trying to figure out the actual video, and here's just the decrypted message:

> http swww yout ubec omwa tchv akcg qhvr te

Comment: Correct! I'm not sure why I didn't accept your answer... The maker of this note is bad at ciphers, tried to make it a youtube video, but did not work. +1 :)

Answer (score -1):

Took me a while, but I think I found it.

Could it be [this one?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)

Comment: I'd upvote this if you could explain the answer. Otherwise, it feels like you're rickrolling everyone. (And yes, this is a spoiler to warn everyone before they click on the link :P)

Comment: Yeah, that's the point. I just couldn't resist